# How to join a table and replace a numeric zip code value with a text zip code value

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I have one table `main_cohort` that has two different columns which contain zip codes in 3 digit and 5 digit numeric form (e.g. 100 or 10017), `zip_value3` and `zip_value5`, and I want to join it with another table `zip_codes` that has these same columns as well as an additional column, `city_name`, that has the text string of the city associated with each zip.

I want to replace the numeric values on the first table with the names of the cities on the second table. So for instance, if I have a customer_id in 'main_cohort' that has a 'zip_value3' of 100, I want to replace that in my output with the value from the `city_name` from the `zip_code` table, which would be New York.

Answer (score 0):

# **Table - tbl_MainCohort** #

CustomerID   Zip_Value3   Zip_Value5

```
  1             100         10000
  2             200         20000
```

**Table - tbl_ZipCodes**

ZipID        Zip_Value3   Zip_Value5   City_Name

```
 1              100         10000       New York
 2              200         20000       California
```

> The following query will give you all Cities for all the ZipCodes in the list where both ZipCode columns from both the tables match.
>
> SELECT City_Name from tbl_ZipCodes codes
>      INNER JOIN tbl_MainCohort main ON codes.Zip_Value3 = main.Zip_Value3
>      AND codes.Zip_Value5 = main.Zip_Value5

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want one city, first checking the 5-digit zip code and then the 3-digit one:

```
select mc.*, coalesce(zc5.city_name, zc3.city_name) as city_name
from main_cohort mc left join
     zip_code zc5
     on mc.zip_value5 = zc5.zip_code left join
     zip_code zc3
     on mc.zip_value3 = zc3.zip_code
```