# How to join the same table on different columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I have a main table that I'm working with, `cohort_table`, that contains zip codes in numerical form in three different columns, `customer_zip`, `payer_zip`, `provider_zip`. I want to join this table with another table, `city_zip` that has numeric zip codes in 3 digit form in a column called `zip3` and 5 digit form in a column called `zip5` as well as the city that each zip code represents, `city_name`. In short, I want to join the tables where `customer_zip` = `zip3`, and where `payer_zip` = `zip5`, and where `provider_zip` = `zip5`. When I run this, I get the results I'm looking for:

```
select *
from cohort_table
left join city_zip on zip3 = customer_zip
```

However, when I try to do all three joins at the same time, I keep getting an error about the tables being ambiguous.

```
select *
from cohort_table
left join city_zip on zip3 = customer_zip
left join city_zip on zip5 = payer_zip
left join city_zip on zip5 = provider_zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Use table aliases!  Qualify column names!

```
select *
from cohort_table c left join
     city_zip zc3
     on zc3.zip3 = c.customer_zip left join
     city_zip zc5
     on zc5.zip5 = c.payer_zip left join
     city_zip zp5
     on zp5.zip5 = c.provider_zip;
```

If you had read my answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960270/how-to-join-a-table-and-replace-a-numeric-zip-code-value-with-a-text-zip-code-va), you would have seen how to do this.  This question is not quite a duplicate (and hence not closed) because you have introduced a third lookup possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This runs, but it looks like it doesn't correctly. When I do each left join individually, I get the results that I want (i.e. the city column matches up with the appropriate zip code), but I get a bunch of nulls when I run all three left joins concurrently.

Comment: @David . . . That is because you are using `select *`.  Use `coalesce()` on the fields you want, as demonstrated in the answer to the previous question.